# Notepad ++ how insert numbers to Questions?

Tags: notepad++

I have file with more than 1000 questions, with the following format;

Question: Which planet is known as the Watery Planet?

Mercury

Earth

Mars

Jupiter

Question: Which of the following is indicated by the color of a star?

Weight

Distance

Temperature

Size

I want to replace "Question" with

Question 1:
Question 2:
Question n:

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602816/notepad-incrementally-replace

Comment: are there always 4 answers?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer: No, it doesn't because the lines are not consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example insert_num.py):

```python
import re

counter = 0
def insert_num(match):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return ' ' + str(counter)
    
editor.rereplace(r'(?<=Question)', insert_num)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> insert_num)
- Done